# Node > express > jade - forms templated sub objects

Tags: json, node.js, express, pug

My question is with sub objects. 
lets have this example:

```
tweets = [{id:1, title:"my tweet", author:{id:"sample", name:"Sample Guy"}}] ;
```

..etc
now if i wanted to save that using express and jade, i would make a form and set an input similar to this:

```
input#title(type="text", name="tweet[title]", value="new tweet")
```

no issues there, but how would i go about setting the author's id/name? my guesses didnt work..

```
input#author(type="text", name="tweet[author[id]]", value="sample")
```

that just returns undefined when i try to `console.log('author '+tweet.author.id) ;` after submitting the put.

Thanks in advance for any assistance,

Answer (score 3):

to reference an object of an object would be

```
tweet[author][id]
```

Comment: huh.. that was remarkably simple and obvious - thanks for the help!

Comment: sometimes the most simple solutions are the hardest to see...you're quite welcome

Answer (score 0):

Each pair of brackets are a level on depth. In addition to named keys you can use numbers or empty brackets, which are useful for infinite-fields.

The following layout

```
input(type="hidden", name="some_field", value="some value")
input(type="hidden", name="tweet[id]", value="tweet id")
input(type="text", name="tweet[author][id]", value="author id")
input(type="text", name="tweet[author][name]", value="author name")


input(type="text", name="numbers[2]", value="2 value")
input(type="text", name="numbers[1]", value="1 value")
input(type="text", name="numbers[0]", value="0 value")

input(type="text", name="more_numbers[]", value="first")
input(type="text", name="more_numbers[]", value="second")
input(type="text", name="more_numbers[]", value="third")
```

will produce, after submit

```
{
    some_field: "some value",
    tweet: {
        id: "tweet id",
        author: {
            id: "author id",
            name: "author name"
        }
    },
    numbers: ["0 value", "1 value", "2 value"],
    more_numbers: ["first", "second", "third"]
}
```

As @Pastor Bones said, you must use

```
tweet[author][id]
```